# Надо создать один фрагмент вместо 800, меняется только индекс TextView/Button/ImageView. И при нажатии на кнопку далее менялось только индекса

Tags: android, kotlin

Создаю приложение ПДД, Надо создать один фрагмент с TextView(вопрос), ImageView,Button(варианты ответа). Проблема: Как менять индексы View при нажатии на кнопку, чтоб все менялось (переход на слеующий экран только все это в одном фрагменте) передать то что ему отображает. Вместо того чтоб создать 800 фрагментов в ручную! Заранее спасибо.

Comment: просто сделайте переменную которая будет инкрементиться когда вы нажимаете на кнопку, и дальше обновляйте содержимое виджетов и всё

Comment: Что за _"индексы View"_? Вы вставляете данные вопроса во View-элементы, после ответа просто берёте данные следующего вопроса и вставляете в те же View-элементы.